# Is UI should be redrawn for iPad n iPhone while developing Universal application programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

When we build a universal application,  Is that we should implement UI seperatey for iPod and IPad?

Our app do not have orientation,splitting functionalities to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should develop the UI seperately for ipod and ipad. For ipod create a folder ipod_content and place your .h and .m files there and same with the ipad. Same thing you need to do in Resources folder for separate xibs.

Answer (score 0):

I depends. You *can* develop the UI so it scales accordingly and is usable on both iPod/iPhone and iPad unchanged (both via Interface Builder and via coding). But quite often you want to do things differently on the iPad since you've got a lot more space available. Unless you don't care about how it looks/feels like ;-)

Comment: Thanks,   An other request: Can you give me a sample 'programatic UI' Universal iphone application .  Thanks In advance